# Is there a way to tell CodeDomProvider Compiler about shared functions in a class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have to check (compile) class before saving it. Now it works unless in the referenced class there is a `Shared` member function, then it breaks.
Here is an excerpt of code in use:

```vb
  Dim _Errors As String = ""
  Dim _CodeCompiler As CodeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic")
  Dim cp As CompilerParameters = New CompilerParameters()
  Try
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.ServiceModel.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.ServiceModel.Web.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.Extensions.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Collections.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Configuration.dll")
    cp.GenerateExecutable = False
    cp.GenerateInMemory = True
    cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False


    Dim _CompilerResults As CompilerResults = Nothing
    _CompilerResults = _CodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, final)

    If (_CompilerResults.Errors.Count > 0) Then
      For Each CompErr As CompilerError In _CompilerResults.Errors
        _Errors += "Line number " + CompErr.Line.ToString() +
         ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber.ToString() +
         ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" + vbCrLf
      Next
      If _Errors <> "" Then
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        File.AppendAllText(file_ & ".errors", _Errors)
        File.WriteAllText(file_ + "." + Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"), final)
        context.Response.Write(_Errors)
        Exit Sub
      End If
    Else
      GC.Collect()
      GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
      File.WriteAllText(file_, final)
      context.Response.Write("DONE!")
    End If
  Finally
    cp = Nothing
    _CodeCompiler.Dispose()
  End Try
```

And the _Errors variable after that call gets:

> "Line number 37, Error Number: BC30456, ''python' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 50, Error Number: BC30456, ''python' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 87, Error Number: BC30456, ''getFunctionFreindlyName' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 88, Error Number: BC30456, ''getFunctionFreindlyName' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 98, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 126, Error Number: BC30456, ''getFunctionFreindlyName' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 127, Error Number: BC30456, ''getFunctionFreindlyName' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 132, Error Number: BC30456, ''getFunctionFreindlyName' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 136, Error Number: BC30456, ''getFunctionFreindlyName' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 138, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 174, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 203, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 216, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 235, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 283, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 298, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 318, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 336, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'Image' is not defined.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 445, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 450, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'StringBuilder' is not defined.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 490, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 511, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 516, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'Regex' is not defined.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 517, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'Match' is not defined.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 523, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'Regex' is not defined.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 534, Error Number: BC30451, ''Regex' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 535, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'StringBuilder' is not defined.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 537, Error Number: BC30451, ''s' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 565, Error Number: BC30451, ''Regex' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 567, Error Number: BC30451, ''s' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 590, Error Number: BC30451, ''NewFuncname' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 611, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'StringBuilder' is not defined.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 684, Error Number: BC30456, ''WriteLocalLog' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 687, Error Number: BC30456, ''WriteLocalLog' is not a member of 'Common'.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 704, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat' is not defined.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 707, Error Number: BC30002, 'Type 'System.Drawing.Image' is not defined.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 718, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 783, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 798, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 815, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 834, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 850, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 924, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 1003, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 1025, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 1047, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 1060, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & "Line number 1075, Error Number: BC30182, 'Type expected.;" & vbCrLf & ""

So how to tell codedom compiler to that the function is IN Common.vb and that it is `Shared`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to include all references to assemblies in the project. Now,because I don't actually know which one should I add (though for another class I've managed somehow to find all, with some code changes...). So after some googling around I've found this one and it worked perfectly:

```
      For Each a As Reflection.Assembly In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        If a.IsDynamic = False Then
          cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(a.Location)
        End If
      Next
```